# A Banach space with the BD property and without the weak Gelfand-Phillips property

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A subset A of X is called Grothendieck if every operator T from X to $c_0$ maps A to a relatively weakly compact set.

A Banach space  has the weak Gelfand-Phillips property (wGP) if every Grothendieck subset of it is relatively weakly compact.

A subset A of X is called limited if every $weak^*$-null sequence in $X^*$ converges uniformly on A; that is, $\sup_{x\in A} |x_n^*(x)|\to 0$.

It is known that a bounded subset A of X is limited if and only if every operator T from X to $c_0$ maps A into a relatively compact set.

A Banach space  has the BD property if every limited subset is relatively weakly compact.

Since every limited set is Grothendieck, every space with the wGP property has the BD property.

Is there an example of a Banach space X with the BD propperty but without the wGP property?

Comment: You should correct your definition of wGP.